# Contradictory text in practicalmeteor:mocha

Tags: meteor, mocha.js

Quoting the official `readme` for https://atmospherejs.com/practicalmeteor/mocha:

> A package for writing and running your meteor app and package tests with mocha...
>
> **Differences with mike:mocha**
>
> ...We do not support writing mocha tests for your app's code... Only code in packages can be tested with this package.

The text contradicts itself, so what is the truth?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's a mistake in the Readme, App testing is supported

---

Originally (~Aug 2015) `practicalmeteor:mocha` only supported package testing, as the differences section says

They added support for App tests later on (~Mar 2016) and added the "App testing with `meteor test`" section

It seems they forgot to update the differences part